# PHP : Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

When I try to openning a xls file which I downloading from my application, I have this error :

> excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. 
>   Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

this is my php code : 
at first, I upload the xls file :

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"])) {
   if (rename($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], $directoryDestination.$nameDestination))        {
      import::importFile($link,$directoryDestination.$nameDestination, $importLib, $excelName,$enddate);
    $_SESSION['message'] = "ok";
}else{
    $_SESSION['erreur'] = "Error";
}
```

then in my function :

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

importFile($link,$filename, $importLib, $excelName,$enddate){
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    // loading Excel file
    $objPHPExcel = IOFactory::load($filename);
    ....
    database 
    ....
    // copy the file
    mkdir($new_path,0777);
    chmod($new_path, 0777);
    copy($filename,$new_path.$excelName);
    unlink($filename);

// then , in other file, I try to download the file
$contents = file_get_contents($filepath);
$mime = mime_content_type($filepath);
$size = filesize($filepath);
$parts = explode("/", $file);
$filename = end($parts);

header("Content-Type: {$mime}");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
print($contents);
exit();
```

I'm using MS 2016 (PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet).
I already tried to change the file extension or to repar it but its not worked

Comment: You unlink before file_get_contents so the file won't exist. Try opening the file in notepad - it's gonna be malformed and most likely have an exception message in there.

Comment: I delete the file after copy, so its always existing. When I try to openning the file with notepad, its malformed but I didnt found an exception message

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @Danny Battison
When I opened the file with Notpad I saw blanks on the top of the file, so I added `ob_end_clean()` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)) just before :

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Type: {$mime}");
```

And its works fine.

Comment: Using ob functions for stuff like this can be a little hacky. Check your PHP files for new lines at the end after a close php tag (and just sack off the close php tag if so!)